# How to make wp7-ish entry forms?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to make a stacked form such as when editing contact details? I suppose it is a StackPanel, but how about TextBlock/TextBox fonts and margins? Just placing them in StackPanel leaves too much of a gap between them vertically, and text in Blocks is not aligned with Box borders.

Comment: Theme resources for wp7, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use {StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle} for your labels. It will set the fontsize, the foreground and the margin for 12,0,12,0. TextBoxes' default margin is the same. If your stackpanel in your layout root has the same margin too, the whole form will be "wp7-ish"... :)
Here is an example:

```
<StackPanel Margin="12,0,12,0"
            Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Strings.Settings_Nickname}"
               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Nickname, Mode=TwoWay}"
             InputScope="PersonalGivenName"/>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Text="{Binding Strings.Settings_NicknameInfo}"
               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
               Margin="12,0,12,24" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Strings.Settings_Language}"
               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="LanguagePicker"
                        Margin="12,0,12,12" />
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Text="{Binding Strings.Settings_LanguageInfo}"
               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kylerr mentioned, always use WP7 in-built Styles for formatting the TextBlocks... it will align itself. Also use MetroGridHelper from NuGet, which will help you in aligning the controls.